# Selecting a random image from a flickr set and appending it to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into a bit of a problem and was hoping to get a little help. I am trying to select a random image from a flickr set and append it to a div to use as a background image. Here is the function:

```
$.getJSON("http://***", function (data){                                                                                                                                   

    var htmlString = ""; 

    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, item){      

            var bkg = data.photoset.photo[i];
            var randomBkg = Math.floor(Math.random() * bkg.length);

            htmlString += '<img src='+ randomBkg.url_o +' />';

    return i < 0;   

    });     

    $('#bg').append(htmlString);

 });
```

If i replace randomBkg.url_o with bkg.url_o it just returns the first image in the set. using it as i have above appends an image tag with "undefined" as the img src. Any help about where i am misguided would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image tag is "undefined" right now, because `Math.floor` returns a `Number`, and Numbers don't have the `url_o` property. If you are just looking to pick out one image out of the set, you don't really need to use `$.each` to iterate over all of the items. You should be able to do the following:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.photoset.photo.length);
var randomImage = data.photoset[index];
var htmlString = = '<img src='+ randomImage.url_o +' />';
```

Comment: Had to specify that i was looking for a photo out of the photoset on randomImange, but this worked great. Cheers.

edited for clarity.

Comment: Cool. Can you click on the up arrow next to my answer if it was helpful? Thanks!

Comment: yeah you got it. i'm new here. 

edit - seems i need 15 reputation to vote up. Will circle back to take care of this once i have the reputation.